# Inverse of a function of a 3rd order

Tags: inverse-function

can someone help me how to find the inverse the following function?

$$z(\zeta)=\frac{1}{\zeta}+m_1\zeta+m_2\zeta^2+m_3\zeta^3$$

In my case, $z$ is a complex number and cannot be zero. And $m_k$ is a constant.

How do I get the inverse of that function? i.e. I want to express $\zeta(z)$? IS it possible to have an explicit formulation? Or, for a given $z$ can we solved $\zeta(z)$ numerically?

## Example

Consider the following function:
$$z(\zeta)=\frac{1}{\zeta}$$

In my understanding, the inverse of the above function is
$$\zeta(z)=\frac{1}{z}$$

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The function $z$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: Oke. Perhaps, my title is not correct. I will revise them.

Comment: You will want to solve the quartic $m_3 \zeta^4+m_2 \zeta^3+x_1 \zeta^2-z \zeta +1=0$ for $\zeta$ in terms of $z$, but solving it with an express formula is [cumbersome](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html). It would indeed probably be easier just to determine the inverse function numerically.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall that correct. I actually want to solve $m_3\zeta^4+m_2\zeta^3+m_1\zeta^2-z\zeta+1=0$. I did use Matlab to numerically solve this using the built-in "roots" function. But somehow it does not work well.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my $z$ is a complex number. I have just fixed it.

Comment: Why do you think the function is injective?

Comment: @copper.hat. To be honest, I don't have a deep knowledge about math. I don't understand what "injective" means.

Comment: For example, $z \mapsto (z-1)z(z+1)$ is not invertible because the values $-1,0,1$ all map to $0$.

Comment: I really cannot answer your comment, @copper.hat

Answer (score 1):

The answer of this question has be given by @nathan.j.mcdougall above. It is essentially solving numerically the following equation

$$m_3\zeta^4+m_2\zeta^3+m_1\zeta^2−z\zeta+1=0$$