# How to find the inverse of a function numerically

Tags: numerical-methods, inverse-function

This is an extension of my previous question posted in here [Inverse of a function of a 3rd order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3083744/inverse-of-a-function-of-a-3rd-order?noredirect=1#comment6357690_3083744)

Now, I have another one which seems to be more complicated. I don't know how to solve them numerically. The function is as follow

$$z(\zeta)=a\left(\frac{1}{\zeta}+m_1\zeta+m_2\zeta^2 \right)+b\left(\zeta+\frac{m_1}{\zeta}+\frac{m_2}{\zeta^2} \right)$$

in which $z$ is a complex number and cannot be zero. $m_k$, $a$ and $b$ are constant.

How to solve this function for $\zeta(z)$?
I am a Matlab user so I would appreciate if someone can refer to any built-in Matlab function that can be used.

## Example

The following $z(\zeta)$ is obtained using the following input:
$$a=-2.08$$
$$b = 4.08$$
$$m_1 = 0.5$$
$$m_2 = -0.03$$
$$\zeta = cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$ for $\theta = [0,2\pi]$

for 
The results is:

`z = [
      2.9400 + 0.0000i
   3.2277 + 2.1618i
   2.2730 + 1.2986i
   0.4557 - 2.2605i
  -1.4094 - 6.6606i
  -2.3950 - 9.7020i
  -1.9857 -10.1025i
  -0.4083 - 7.8642i
   1.5321 - 3.9596i
   2.9400 - 0.0000i
]`

Thanks!

Comment: It can be that there is no algebraic expression for the inverse. Does it suffice to have an algorithm that finds the input value, when given the output value $z$?

Comment: Hi @MattiP. Yes. The input $\zeta = e^{i \theta}$ where $\theta$ is from $0$ to $2\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scale your equation 
$$z=a\left(\frac{1}{\zeta}+m_1\zeta+m_2\zeta^2 \right)+b\left(\zeta+\frac{m_1}{\zeta}+\frac{m_2}{\zeta^2} \right)$$
by $\zeta^2$ and obtain the equivalent form
$$z \zeta^2=a\left(\zeta+m_1\zeta^3+m_2\zeta^4 \right)+b\left(\zeta^3+m_1\zeta+m_2 \right),$$
which can be reordered into
$$ 0 = am_2 \zeta^4+(am_1+b)\zeta^3-z\zeta^2+(bm_1+a)\zeta+bm_2.$$
The right-hand side is a polynomial in $\zeta$ of order at most $4$. MATLAB has a built-in function called [roots](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/roots.html) which will compute all the roots of a polynomial by finding the eigenvalues of the companion matrix.